# Не запускается файл jar: Could not find the main class

Tags: java

Сделал программу на Яве, ошибок в коде нет. С Нетбинса запуск происходит, а вот с папки dist запускаемый файл test.jar нехочет. Пишет:

> `Could not find the main class: test.anketa. Program will exit.`

Не удалось найти основной класс: test.anketa. Программа будет закрыта.

Comment: открой jar архиватором и посмотри на содержимое - должна быть структура:

    `/
        /META-INF
        /test
            anketa.class
    `

Answer (score 1):

В MANIFEST.MF нужно указать Main-Сlass

Answer (score 0):

Отвечать конечно поздно, но, может, будет полезно тому, кто зайдет сюда в поисках ответа. У меня была такая же проблема. Вздумалось мне с 7 джавы перейти на 8. Все прошло успешно, всем проектам поставила 8 джаву и собрала заново jar-ы (потому что они вдруг перестали запускаться - такая же проблема как в этом вопросе). Но и после того, как я все пересобрала, проблема осталась. Решилось все тем, что я рядом с 8 джавой снова поставила 7. Хоть проекты остались на 8, но все работает как надо.

Answer (score 0):

Проверь правильно ли ты описал создание артефакта в структуре проекта. Возможно стоит явно указать класс Main в настройках артефакта.
[Хоть это и по IntelliJ IDEA но может быть полезно](https://javadevblog.com/sozdaem-yspolnyaemyj-jar-v-intellij-idea.html)